# Looking for network simulator (subnets, routers, etc..)

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router, modem

I am looking for network simulator (subnets, routers,wireless  etc..) to study for an interview that I have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could take a look at these:

[GNS3](https://www.gns3.com/)

[visual - netkit](http://code.google.com/p/visual-netkit/)

[OMNeT++](http://www.omnetpp.org/)

I've use d GNS3 in the past and it was pretty good, I haven't any personal experience with the other two.

Answer (score 4):

[**NS2**](http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/) is the open source standard, while [Opnet](http://www.opnet.com/solutions/network_planning_operations/) is the commercial standard. NS2 is gradually being replaced by [**NS3**](http://www.nsnam.org/).

I've used NS2 extensively (while working at Qualcomm) and it's very powerful.  See also the [entry on network simulation on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_simulator), which also lists these applications.

Comment: Highly recommended NS2.

Comment: +1 on NS2.  The only draw back is TCL but even so, it is worth the effort.

Answer (score 4):

from my own experience:
1- Packet tracer: is just for learning. they taught us when we were taking CCNA, and cisco materials. It is quite simple and GUI oriented.Normally, it a good idea to show that your know it and tell that it is simple.and it could serve the purpose of subnetting, routing, wireless, and so many things , but as I said , it is quite simple.

**however**, when you are talking about network simulators through which you can do your own  modification, your can not use packet tracer, **NS2, Omnet++,and NS3** should be your options. These simulators are so powerful and need some time to get it. 
My recommendation for a starter, Omnet++ has some good GUI basic modules, it allows you to learn simple things easily,refer to some basic tutorials and you could get started with your project within short time. NS2 or NS3 they are quite hard(in my opinion) and they do not tend to have GUI. 
*To make it easy for you,* i think you should go for **omnet++** and here is the basic [tutorial](http://www.omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/part1.html)
.

Answer (score 2):

My preference is Omnet++. I'll admit that I've not worked with NS2, but Omnet++ satisfied all my requirements for my PhD research.

Omnet is  a very versatile simulator, but the versatility comes at the cost of added complexity. You should already be familiar with C++, and be prepared to write lots of it.

Omnet also contains a rich set if libraries that allow you to model wireless networks, GSM networks, vehicular ad-hoc networks or peer-to-peer networks to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

There is also **[Packet Tracer](http://www.cisco.com/web/learning/netacad/course_catalog/PacketTracer.html)** from Cisco (latest version as of June 2010 is v5.3). It is free for Cisco student

[image]